# Force Update of a Magento Extension

Tags: magento

I have updated the .php files in the adminhtml directory of a Magento Community Extension. Is there any way to force Magento to recognize this change and make the update without having to uninstall and reinstall the extension? I am running magento 1.14.0.1 if that will affect it. I have tried flushing the cache, refreshing it, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you have updated files so upgrade is almost done for that module.
One point you need to check is if there were any DB related update needed.

If yes then you need to specify a higher version in XML file and your sql queries will be fired to effect data base tables.

Also in case you have compiler mode on you need to switch it off.